# Not staying signed in with omniauth-facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, session, session-cookies, omniauth

I've followed [Ryan's cast on signing in with omniauth-facebook](http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication) and the signing in works great.

The problem I'm having though is staying signed in. Right now I'm signed in until I close the browser window. If I open my browser again and go back to my website I'm signed out. Same goes for other people on other machines and other Facebook accounts.

I'm not too familiar with the workings of sessions and Facebook authentication so it's hard for me to analyse what is going wrong exactly.

Maybe some of you know what is going on? Thanks in advance!

My code:

application_controller:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
helper_method :current_user
```

sessions_controller:

```
def create
 user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
 session[:user_id] = user.id
 redirect_to root_url
end
```

user.rb:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.name = auth.info.name
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.pic_url = auth.info.image
    user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
    user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
    user.save!
  end
end
```

omniauth.rb:

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, CONFIG[:facebook_app_id], CONFIG[:facebook_app_secret], scope 'email', display: 'popup'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's straight in the Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Omniauthable,-sign-out-action-and-rememberable)

on signup in `SessionsController` do

```
remember_me(user)
```

and be sure to have `:rememberable` passed as Devise option in your user model.

Side note - I think you use quite outdated flow, right now encouraged solution is to have `OmniauthCallbacksController` I think.

Answer (score 1):

May be problem here is when you close the browser the session is getting expired.

Why can't you use devise gem for signing the user.

If you use devise gem for your User table, you will get an option called "Remeber Me", you can set this flag as true when the user is loggedin.

For more info on devise refer - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

This may solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion NaveenKumar. I would rather not use more gems and code than absolutely needed and this should be able to work without Device.